# Bower install command not working on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gruntjs, bower

This is my output from running bower:

```
PS F:\tmp\ember3\demo2> bower install ember
bower cloning git://github.com/components/ember
bower cached git://github.com/components/ember
bower fetching ember
PS F:\tmp\ember3\demo2>
```

After running the above command, I see nothing generated/copied in the 'demo2' directory.
I only have the .bowerrc file in the 'demo2' directory:

```
PS F:\tmp\ember3\demo2> ls


    Directory: F:\tmp\ember3\demo2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          6/1/2013   2:23 AM         81 .bowerrc


PS F:\tmp\ember3\demo2> cat .bowerrc
{
        "name": "demo2",
        "version": "0.0.1",
    "directory": "bower_components"
}

PS F:\tmp\ember3\demo2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok it seems the issue was the git was not on my 'path'

Comment: If this was the answer, please mark it as the correct answer, so future visitors know what works.

Comment: How you added on path? :-/

Comment: Adding git to your path: 1. Press `Windows`+`R`; and enter `control sysdm.cpl` to open System Properties; 2. Click the `System Variables` button in the `Advanced` tab; 3. In the bottom box labeled `System Variables`, select `PATH` and click `Edit`; 4. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;` (You may have to adjust the paths if git is installed somewhere else); 5. OK all open dialogs. Git should now be added to your path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run bower from Git Bash. In windows bower doesn't work from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

install node.js then use node package manager, npm to install bower via "npm install -g bower" after that you can now user bower via "bower install package-name"